# Proftpd - 0kb file after upload

Tags: java, ftp

I've been searching for quite some time and couldn't find a solution.
I'm trying to upload a file from my computer to my ftp Server. But everytime I try, I only create a 0kb file.

I've tried

1. turning the firewall off
2. chmod -R 775 on the folder
3. 20 different version of the client
4. passive transfer mode
5. Binary file type
6. Binary type transfer mode
7. Using the newest commons-net libary ( 3.3 )

Related:

[0 kb file created once FTP is done in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718338/0-kb-file-created-once-ftp-is-done-in-java)

[FTP a file to server, but it the result arrives with zero byte size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707682/ftp-a-file-to-server-but-it-the-result-arrives-with-zero-byte-size)

```
public static void goforIt(){
    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    ftpClient.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));
    try {

        ftpClient.connect("xxx.xxx.xxx.xx");

        ftpClient.login("xx", "xx");
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        //ftpClient.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        boolean w = ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("/var/www/xx");


        if (ftpClient.getReplyString().contains("250")) {
            InputStream in = null;
            try{
                in = new FileInputStream(new File("xx.mp4"));
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }

            ftpClient.sendCommand("PWD");


            boolean result = ftpClient.storeFile("/var/www/public_videos/xx.mp4", in);
            System.out.println(ftpClient.getReplyString() + result);

            in.close();
            ftpClient.logout();
            ftpClient.disconnect();
        }

    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Log:

```
220 ProFTPD 1.3.4a Server (Debian) [::ffff:xx.xxx.xx.xx]
USER xx
331 Password required for xx
PASS xx
230 User xx logged in
TYPE I
200 Type set to I
CWD /var/www/xx
250 CWD command successful
PWD
257 "/var/www/xx" is the current directory
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xx,xxx,xxx,xx).
STOR /var/www/public_videos/xx.mp4
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for /var/www/xx/xx.mp4
226 Transfer complete
226 Transfer complete
true
QUIT
221 Goodbye.
```

Result:

http://puu.sh/e6pVx/051c175f9e.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing

```
ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
```

lead to the solution of my problem

Comment: In addition to using passive mode on the client, ensure the proftpd server has `PassivePorts` declared, and these ports are open